# ¿Como validar en una linea de texto exista coincidencia de palabras repetidas

Tags: regex, perl, preg-match

es decir, validar una cadena donde se repite (2 veces) con expresiones regulares, por ejemplo. Si tengo lo siguiente:

```
la respuesta movida tendrá que ser movida nuevamente.

la respuesta ***movida*** tendrá que ser ***movida*** nuevamente.
```

o también si tengo correos electrónicos:

```
from: "***lalala@micorreo.com***" <***lalala@micorreo.com***>
```

validar los correos repetidos.
¿Cómo puedo realizar una validación con expresiones regulares, pero si tengo diferentes que no lo valide. Mientras tengo esto.

```
/[\w.!#$%&*+\/=?{|||+@[\w-íritu+(?:\.[\wíritu+)/
```

Luego tengo que validarlo en perl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muchas gracias por la respuesta, en realidad requiero para correos.
verifico que sean repetidos, lo valido con esto.
@[\w-]+(?:.[\w]+)

o esto

/[\w.!#$%&*+/=?{|}]+@[\w-]+(?:.[\w]+)/

pero validar los correos, pero ¿Como saber si son repetidos?.

from: "**usuario@micorreo.com**" <**usuario@micorreo.com**>

from: "*hola@experto.com*" <*usuario@micorreo.com*>

la linea anterior no son repetidos, sin embargo lo matchea.

T.T

GRacias de antemano.

Comment: Es una respuesta o parte de tu pregunta?

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo es partir la línea en palabras, y meterlas en un hash, sumando 1 por cada aparición de la palabra.

Al final, aquellas palabras que tengan en el hash un valor superior a 1, significarán que están repetidas.

Si necesitas obligatoriamente resolverlo con expresiones regulares, podrías intentarlo con expresiones extendidas:

```
perl -E '"la respuesta movida tendrá que ser movida que nuevamente." =~ /\b(\w+)(*SKIP)\b.+?\1(?{ say $1 })(*FAIL)/;'
movida
que
```

Con un patrón como `/b(\w+)/` puedes capturar palabras, pero no direcciones de correo. Eso necesitará un patrón distinto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, en realidad requiero para correos. 
verifico que sean repetidos, lo valido con esto.
@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w]+)

o esto

/[\w.!#$%&*+\/=?{|}]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w]+)/
 
pero validar los correos, pero ¿Como saber si son repetidos?. 

from: "usuario@micorreo.com" <usuario@micorreo.com>
from: "hola@experto.com" <usuario@micorreo.com>

Comment: Necesitas una expresión regular que capture toda la dirección de correo. Podría ser: /([\w.+-]+@[\w-]+(?:[.][\w-]+))/ Una vez capturado, ya puedes usarlo para buscar repetidos: perl -E '$mail = qr/[\w.+-]+@[\w-]+(?:[.][\w-]+)/; q("usuario@micorreo.com" <usuario@micorreo.com>) =~ /\b($mail)(*SKIP)\b.+?\1(?{ say $1 })(*FAIL)/;'

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta maestro, ¿puedo ser su aprendiz?. lo Termine de esta manera.

$validar = qr/[\w.!#$%&*+\/=?{|}]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w]+)/;
$de = qr/\b($validar)(*SKIP)\b.+?\1/;

$texto = <STDIN>;

if( $texto =~ $validar and $texto =~ $de){
    print "Bienvenido";
}else{
    print "Fuera de aca palomilla";
}

lo puse de esta forma para ejecutarlo, ahora lo que haré es un plugin en perl. Nuevamente muchas por su ayuda.

Comment: Estás utilizando demasiados caracteres especiales para la parte de usuario de un correo electrónico. Y en la comprobación, no te hace falta buscar por $validar. Con $de es suficiente. Y si el texto consiste de un máximo de una dirección de correo, te sobra "(*SKIP)". Tendrás mejor soporte nuestro en el foro de Perl en Español. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el ayuda, Una consulta. Como realizar un plugin, osea primero armar para luego probarlo.

Comment: Que tal buen día, una consulta, seguí ejemplo y documentación de spamassassin tales como esto:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPAMASSASSIN/PluginWritingTips

https://metacpan.org/pod/Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin

y un ejemplo desde github, todo relacionado para crear un plugin para spamassassin. Realice uno guiandome pero no hace un match al mi correo de prueba. en el archivo *.cf puse esto:


loadplugin Probando /spamassassin/Probando.pm
header PROBANDO eval:check_for_probando()
score  PROBANDO 50.0
describe PROBANDO From and To is the same

Comment: y en el archivo Probando.pm puse lo siguiente

package Probando;
use Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin;

our @ISA = qw(Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin);

sub new {
    my ( $class, $mailsa ) = @_;

    $class = ref($class) || $class;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new($mailsa);
    bless ($self, $class);

    $self->register_eval_rule ("check_for_probando");

    return $self;
}

Comment: sub check_for_probando{
    my ( $self, $msg )  = @_;
    my $check_from      = lc( $msg->get('From:addr') );

    my $validar = qr/\b([\w.!#$%&*+\/=?{|}]+@[\w-]+(?:\.[\w]+))\b.+?\1/m;

    Mail::SpamAssassin::Plugin::dbg(
                "From: '$check_from");

    if($check_from =~ $validar){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }

}

1;


Lo estoy haciendo para que detecte si los correos entrantes son distintos, que los bloquee. El regexp valida correos repetidos. Disculpe las molestias y gracias por la ayuda brindada anteriormente, Saludos.

Comment: StackOverflow no es un foro, no es práctico para seguir un proyecto o desarrollo. Si quieres mejor soporte, entra en el foro de Perl en Español (búscalo en Google).